# Why this consumer-producer thread is frozen?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, delegates

I've made this producer-consumer sample, but I don't know why it freezes at the end.
Where is the problem? If I put a breakpoint at line setNum(-99); and then after break continue it finishes OK.
Please also tell me if this code is ok and threadsafe. It must work like that, so meanwhile consumer is processing its given value, all other values from producer must be ignored.
I am very new to multithreading.

```
class Program
{
    delegate void SetNumberDelegate(int number);
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        ConsumerClass consumerClass = new ConsumerClass();
        SetNumberDelegate setNum = new SetNumberDelegate(consumerClass.setNumber);
        Thread.Sleep(20);
        int num;
        int count = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Start");
        while (count++ < 100)
        {
            num = rnd.Next(0, 100);
            Console.WriteLine("Generated number {0}", num);
            if (num > 30)
            {
                setNum(num);
            }
        }
        setNum(-99);
        Console.WriteLine("End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

class ConsumerClass : IDisposable
{
    private int number;
    private object locker = new object();
    private EventWaitHandle _wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);
    private Thread _consumerThread;

    public ConsumerClass()
    {
        number = -1;
        _consumerThread = new Thread(consumeNumbers);
        _consumerThread.Start();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        setNumber(-99);
        _consumerThread.Join();         
        _wh.Close();
    }

    public void setNumber(int num)
    {
        if (Monitor.TryEnter(locker))
        {
            try
            {
                number = num;
                Console.WriteLine("Setting number {0}", number);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Ensure that the lock is released.
                Monitor.Exit(locker);
            }
            _wh.Set();
        }
    }

    public void consumeNumbers()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Monitor.Enter(locker);
            if (number > -1)
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Processing number:{0}", number);
                    // simulate some work with number e.g. computing and storing to db
                    Thread.Sleep(20);
                    Console.WriteLine("Done");
                    number = -1;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Monitor.Exit(locker);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (number == -99)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Consumer thread exit");
                    return;
                }
                Monitor.Exit(locker);
                _wh.WaitOne();         // No more tasks - wait for a signal
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions for CodeReview should present working snippets looking for tips for refactoring, pattern usage etc. If something is not working, the question should be posted to StackOverflow.

Comment: anybody who has privileges, please move it to stackoverflow. Thanks.

Comment: you can flag and ask moderator to migrate ...

Comment: It works fine and if I add Thread.Sleep(500); after the producer loop ends (before: setNum(-99);) it works and end consumer thread ends just fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite setNumber like this to see your problem:

```
public void setNumber(int num) {
    if (Monitor.TryEnter(locker)) {
        // etc..
    }
    else Console.WriteLine("Number {0} will never make it to the consumer", num);
}
```

You'll have to block, waiting for the consumer to be ready to consume or use a queue.

Answer (score 0):

`Monitor.TryEnter(locker);` will usually fail (including for -99) so you aren't going to set a fair number of the values, which is why the output is lacking in setting statements.  This is because it will not wait to acquire the lock it will just return false.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be in the last part of the code. You're holding the lock when you execute this:

```
        else
        {
            if (number == -99)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Consumer thread exit");
                return;
            }
            Monitor.Exit(locker);
            _wh.WaitOne();         // No more tasks - wait for a signal
        }
```

So if `number == 99`, the method returns without releasing the lock.

Your `ConsumeNumbers` method is overly complex. You can simplify it:

```
while (true)
{
    _wh.WaitOne();
    lock (locker)
    {
        if (number == -99)
            break;
        if (number > -1)
        {
            // process the number.
            number = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

That will do the same thing, and is much simpler code.

By the way, the construct:

```
lock (locker)
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

is the same as:

```
Monitor.Enter(locker);
try
{
    // do stuff here
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(locker);
}
```